# How to integrate bing spell-check key in microsoft botframework v4 along with other keys?

Tags: botframework, bing

Even though i add the bing spell check key along with other keys in the .bot file, its not working .

Is there a way you could integrate the key in v4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Spell Check Middleware` provided by the Bot Builder Community.

For `C#`:

- It is available through NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Middleware.SpellCheck/
- Sources: https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Middleware.SpellCheck

To use it, you have to add the Service in the declaration:

```
services.AddBot<Bot>((options) => {
    options.CredentialProvider = new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(Configuration);

    // more middleware
    options.Middleware.Add(new SpellCheckMiddleware(Configuration));
});
```

And your configuration must include:

```
{
  "SpellCheckKey": "<YOUR SPELL CHECK KEY HERE>",
  "SpellCheckCountryCode": "sv",
  "SpellCheckMarket": "sv-SE" 
}
```

See the source page for more details on how to use it

---

For Node.js:

- Npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@botbuildercommunity/spell-check-middleware
- Sources / How to use it: https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-spell-check-middleware/README.md

Comment: And if you are using LUIS for intent recognition, you could also add it directly in the LUIS call by setting `spellCheck=true`.

Comment: There is no mention of LUIS here

Comment: @Mick I am using LUIS but i cant find a way to insert the key in LUIS itself but can do per sessions

Comment: @Mick Me too using LUIS but do not find a way to pass spellCheck=true ... how do we do that ?